# imGoogleMaps, skip wrong address and continue loading markers on Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps JS API "imGoogleMaps". I get the error "Sorry, we are unable to gecode address: ..." and the Map stops loading (stays grey). Somebody knows how to skip this wrong address and continue loading the other addresses?

I want it to show a lot of markers (addresses) on a Map. It loads the addresses from a JSON file.